Firebase ab test. ios project with activation event doesn't see any user
Have android and ios projects with the same events and created ab tests for each of them on firebase. Tests applied for all users, added activation event screen_view_activation.
screen_view_activation is a custom firebase event, which created from event_name=screen_view, firebase_screen={name of screen}. It always send after remote config fetch and activated. After start testing checked analytics in bigquery, see multiple numbers of screen_view_activation events for both platforms
For android test works well, see test results, but for ios even after several days still see  users. Why activation event doesn't trigger test(if leave activation event empty, test see users)?

This is known bug on Firebase side. I have reported this issue few months ago and they are working on this.
The problem is that it is not possible to use "Custom event" (event created in GA4/Firebase UI) as "Activation event" for iOS AB test Experiments.
Solution #1 is simple, but requires mobile app release. Generate the "Activation event" on mobile app side via logEvent method. This ensures, that AB test Experiment runs on iOS as well.
--- Update:
Solution #2:
Update Firebase SDK to at least 10.25.0. Upon releases notes, it seems as issue is fixed. https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios#version_10250_-_april_30_2024
